# kivy Python: animated picture while waiting Login Password check code

Tags: python, popup, kivy, animated-gif

I need to open popup window when I check the Login Password.
I will put the Login Password code in the place of time code after that.
But even with time code, I can't open the animated Gif and after 10s the window is closed automatically.
This is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import time
kv = """
<Test@AnchorLayout>:
    AsyncImage:
        source: 'wait.gif'
        anim_delay: 0.1
Test:"""



class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)
        anim = Builder.load_string(kv)
        layout.add_widget(anim)
        popup = Popup(content=layout)  
        popup.open()  
        print('Hello world')
        now = time.time()
        future = now + 10
        while time.time() < future:
        popup.dismiss()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another answer which works perfectly:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
#rest of the code above
    def build(self):
            layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10)
            anim = Builder.load_string(kv)
            layout.add_widget(anim)
            popup = Popup(content=layout)
            popup.open()
            print('Hello world')
Clock.schedule_once(App().get_running_app().stop,10)#....rest of the code below
```

u can use the clock feature. idk why i forgot it lol ;D

Comment: [Please click here for more info](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

Comment: Thank you again for your answer.
Your code clode the popup window after 10s.
However, I need to see the function "popup.dismiss()".
In fact, my first question is to start "checking Login Password" and "open Popup" at the same time. When I finish the checking operation I close the Popup. So, I don't know exactly the duration of checking step. So to simplify my code, I change the "Login Password code" by 2 "time" lines.
For this reason, I need to see the Popup open and Popup dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

see closely, `popup.dismiss()` must be an indented block

```
#↓
if time.time()>future:
    #         ↑
    popup.dismiss()
```

if you dismiss the popup while the time is less than future nothing will happen...... also note than the computer is able to find the right gif file

[my code is working :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR73o.png)

Comment: please accept my answer if it worked for you coz it is working for me

Comment: Thanks to your answer, the gif file is open in a new Popup.
However, it is not close after 10s.
I think that the code test only one time if the "time.time()>future" is True, so create a Var V=1 after 10s "time.sleep(10)" and I change the condition:
if V==1:   ↑
    popup.dismiss()

But the problem still persists